# Permission for Continuous access to microphone

Tags: ios, microphone

I am creating an app on iOS and it requires constant access to the device's mic. Is it possible to request continuous background access to microphone on iOS? The app should be able to receive mic data even when the screen is switched off for prolonged durations of time.

I have tried using Background tasks, but it turns out that Background access to microphone on iOS is restricted to a couple of minutes at most. I need the app to have access to mic data at all times. Can we maybe use accessibility permissions for this to work?